# Formula to find the last populated cell in a column and add to it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If column A is marked with an X, the adjacent cell in column B will find the last populated cell in column B and simply +1 to that.

For example: If A1 is marked and B1 is HF2056, and it skips a row so that A3 is marked with an X, B3 would need to auto fill to be HF2057.[Image with fake numbers for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5pdJ.png)

So how do I formulate it so that if a cell in column A is marked with an X, the adjacent cell in column B will find the last filled cell in B with data and fill in the new number?

I feel like this may be an ISBLANK formula but I can't figure it out.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what else could be shown in Column A? how about provide some sample data to demonstrate what you expect to achieve?

Comment: ^ Agreed with @TerryW. Without sample data this question is unclear. It sounds like a simple `INDEX` formula in B.

Comment: Column A will always either be blank or be marked with an X. The idea is that if the cell in A is marked with an X, then the cell in B will look up the last populated cell in column B and simply +1 to that.

Comment: I've added an image to help explain what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assume : `A1` is X and `B1` is HF2056, `A2` is blank, `A3` is X

Then, in `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(A2="","",LEFT(LOOKUP(1,0/(A$1:A1="X"),B$1:B1),2)&RIGHT(LOOKUP(1,0/(A$1:A1="X"),B$1:B1),4)+1)
```

And, formula result:

```
B2 : (blank)
B3 : HF2057
```

Remark :

The above formula result will give max number in HF10000.

If you want the number keep to increase by 1, the `B2` formula will be changed to :

```
=IF(A2="","",LEFT(LOOKUP(1,0/(A$1:A1="X"),B$1:B1),2)&RIGHT(LOOKUP(1,0/(A$1:A1="X"),B$1:B1),LEN(LOOKUP(1,0/(A$1:A1="X"),B$1:B1))-2)+1)
```